# How do I fix my ELAN Touchpad Driver (Windows 8 Pro)?

Tags: windows-8, touchpad

Whenever I use a Windows 8 app (e.g. Mail) and I just move my mouse up using the touchpad, it brings up the configuration bar (the one that comes out when you right-click).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's interpreting it as a swipe up from the bottom edge. You can disable **Edge Swipes** via the **Mouse Properties** Control Panel applet:

[image: 1]